# Unable to scrape content from next pages with complex layout

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, python-requests

I've been trying to scrape tabular content from a [webpage](https://registers.maryland.gov/RowNetWeb/Estates/frmEstateSearch2.aspx) using requests module. The data of that table spread across multiple pages. I wish to keep on parsing until all the next pages are exhausted.

To populate the table on that webpage, all it is required to do is select `Baltimore` as county, date range from `08-08-2020` to `01-01-2021` and press the search button leaving everything as they are.

The following script can parse data from few pages (12 or something) and then breaks. There is no next page button available in there, so I don't understand how to modify the logic within the script to grab all the next pages. To go on to the next page, it is necessary to use the page number within the value of `__EVENTTARGET`.

This is what I've been trying with:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

coreid = 'dgSearchResults$ctl24$ctl{}'
link = 'https://registers.maryland.gov/RowNetWeb/Estates/frmEstateSearch2.aspx'

p = 1

with requests.Session() as s:
    s.headers['User-Agent'] = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.104 Safari/537.36'
    r = s.get(link)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,"lxml")
    payload = {i['name']:i.get('value','') for i in soup.select('input[name]')}
    payload.pop('cmdClear')
    payload['cboCountyId'] = '3' #Baltimore (next to county)
    payload['DateOfFilingFrom'] = '08-08-2020' #date from (under range)
    payload['DateOfFilingTo'] = '01-01-2021'   #date to (under range)
    payload['cboPartyType'] = 'Decedent'

    while True:
        res = s.post(link,data=payload)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")
        
        if not soup.select_one("table#dgSearchResults tr:has(> td > a[href^='frmDocketImages.aspx'])"): break
        
        for item in soup.select("table#dgSearchResults tr:has(> td > a[href^='frmDocketImages.aspx'])"):
            data = [i.text for i in item.select("td")]
            print(data)

        payload = {i['name']:i.get('value','') for i in soup.select('input[name]')}
        payload['__EVENTTARGET'] = coreid.format(str(p).zfill(2))
        try:
            payload.pop('cmdSearchNew')
        except KeyError: pass
        print('-------------->',payload['__EVENTTARGET'])
        p+=1
```

> How can I scrape data from all the next pages using requests module?

Comment: i'm not sure i understand your problem well but it repeats the last page because you never exit the while loop. i think the culprit is your try block, if `cmdSearchNew` tells if there's a new page then `except KeyError: break` should do the trick

Comment: Repeat the last number of the first page, as in 10 here @diggusbickus. The script can't go on to the page 12,13,14 and so on.

Comment: The third line under while loop is for breaking the loop.

Comment: i ran the script. it stopped at `dgSearchResults$ctl24$ctl12` with no repetition. if i circumvent your break the data is repeating yes. do you think there's more data because the site tells there are hundreds of pages or do you know there is more data?

Comment: Yes, I know for sure. I manually traversed al least 350 pages to check it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The site you are scraping is generated by asp.net WebForms.  Everything a user can interact with is considered a "control" and will have dynamically generated identifiers that depend on their sequence within a container.  These identifiers are not always reflected in the id attribute of an element.  When a user interacts with the page, a function called `__doPostBack(eventTarget, eventArgs)` is fired, which fills out a few standard hidden form fields, then posts to the server to get an updated page.  The `eventTarget` is the asp.net identifier for the clicked element.

Your container in this case is the table with ID `dgSearchResults`.

The paging navigation on this site is a child of the container table, so navigation will work the same way, with a postback using `__EVENTTARGET`.  In order for you to use requests to step through the site, you need to know the index of your current page, you need to find the link to the next page, and you have to set the `__EVENTTARGET` in your post to the identifier of that link.

First, we are going to use regex a few times, so let's import it:

```
import re
```

Next, to avoid slamming the website we are going to put in a short random wait between post requests.  This wasn't part of your question but it's an important consideration.  For this we'll use `random.uniform()` and `time.sleep()`:

```
from random import uniform 
from time import sleep
```

You've already declared `p = 1` to track the page number.  To make the code a little clearer, I would change `p` to `page_num`, initialize it to `0`, then increment it after your post request in each iteration of the page loop.  Also, before each post request, we are going to wait a random amount of time between 500 and 1000 milliseconds (you can adjust these as you see fit).  This wait will avoid slamming the server, and the randomness helps keep your code from looking like a bot in the server logs:

```
page_num = 0

while True:
    wait_time = uniform(0.5, 1.0)
    sleep(wait_time)

    res = s.post(link,data=payload)
    page_num += 1

    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")
    if not soup.select_one("table#dgSearchResults tr:has(> td > a[href^='frmDocketImages.aspx'])"): break
```

The row containing the paging links has class `grid-pager`, so let's grab it:

```
nav_row = soup.select_one("table#dgSearchResults tr.grid-pager")
if nav_row is None: break
```

The html of this row on the first page is:

```
<tr class="grid-pager" align="right">
<td colspan="7">
    <span>1</span>&nbsp;
    <a href="javascript:__doPostBack('dgSearchResults$ctl24$ctl01','')">2</a>&nbsp;
    <a href="javascript:__doPostBack('dgSearchResults$ctl24$ctl02','')">3</a>&nbsp;
    <a href="javascript:__doPostBack('dgSearchResults$ctl24$ctl03','')">4</a>&nbsp;
    <a href="javascript:__doPostBack('dgSearchResults$ctl24$ctl04','')">5</a>&nbsp;
    <a href="javascript:__doPostBack('dgSearchResults$ctl24$ctl05','')">6</a>&nbsp;
    <a href="javascript:__doPostBack('dgSearchResults$ctl24$ctl06','')">7</a>&nbsp;
    <a href="javascript:__doPostBack('dgSearchResults$ctl24$ctl07','')">8</a>&nbsp;
    <a href="javascript:__doPostBack('dgSearchResults$ctl24$ctl08','')">9</a>&nbsp;
    <a href="javascript:__doPostBack('dgSearchResults$ctl24$ctl09','')">10</a>&nbsp;
    <a href="javascript:__doPostBack('dgSearchResults$ctl24$ctl10','')">...</a>
</td>
```

So, `nav_row` is a table row element with a single cell containing links to additional results.  Your current page is the text of a `<span>` tag, and the link to the next result set is always the next `<a>`.

To get the `span`, use a regex to find `page_num`.  Even though the `span` you are looking for is the only one in the row, finding `page_num` ensures that you get the one you want in case any additional `span`s are added down the line.

Let's get that span and the link to the next page:

```
page_span = nav_row.find('span', string=re.compile(rf'\b{page}\b'))
next_page_link = page_span.find_next_sibling('a')
if next_page_link is None: break
```

If there's no `next_page_link` we are at the end of the list (or something has gone wrong - that's up to you to check), so we break.  The html of `next_page_link` is:

```
<a href="javascript:__doPostBack('dgSearchResults$ctl24$ctl01','')">2</a>
```

The `eventTarget` - which is the value we need for `__EVENTTARGET` in the post request - is the first argument in `__doPostBack()` in the link's `href`:

```
href = next_page_link.get('href')
```

Next we can use regex again to grab the identifer we need for `__EVENTTARGET`.  The way WebForms works, it will always be the first quoted item after `doPostBack` and is always required.

```
match = re.search(r'doPostBack\([\'\"]([^\'\"]+)', href)
event_target = match[1]
```

Note that the code assumes there will always be a match.  You might need to test that or add your own error handling.

Now that we have `event_target`, we can build the payload:

```
payload = {i['name']:i.get('value','') for i in soup.select('input[name]')}
payload['__EVENTTARGET'] = event_target
payload.pop('cmdSearchNew', None)

print('-------------->',payload['__EVENTTARGET'])
```

And that's it.  Your code will navigate to the next page on the next iteration of the loop.  Putting it all together and running it using the inputs you specified will navigate through all 96 pages returned:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
from random import uniform
from time import sleep

link = 'https://registers.maryland.gov/RowNetWeb/Estates/frmEstateSearch2.aspx'

with requests.Session() as s:
    s.headers['User-Agent'] = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.104 Safari/537.36'
    r = s.get(link)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,"lxml")
    payload = {i['name']:i.get('value','') for i in soup.select('input[name]')}
    payload.pop('cmdClear')
    payload['cboCountyId'] = '3' #Baltimore (next to county)
    payload['DateOfFilingFrom'] = '08-08-2020' #date from (under range)
    payload['DateOfFilingTo'] = '01-01-2021'   #date to (under range)
    payload['cboPartyType'] = 'Decedent'

    page_num = 0

    while True:
        wait_time = uniform(0.5, 1.0)
        sleep(wait_time)

        res = s.post(link,data=payload)
        page_num += 1

        soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")
        if not soup.select_one("table#dgSearchResults tr:has(> td > a[href^='frmDocketImages.aspx'])"): break
        
        for item in soup.select("table#dgSearchResults tr:has(> td > a[href^='frmDocketImages.aspx'])"):
            data = [i.text for i in item.select("td")]
            print(data)

        nav_row = soup.select_one("table#dgSearchResults tr.grid-pager")
        if nav_row is None: break

        page_span = nav_row.find('span', string=re.compile(rf'\b{page_num}\b'))
        next_page_link = page_span.find_next_sibling('a')
        if next_page_link is None: 
            break

        href = next_page_link.get('href')

        match = re.search(r'doPostBack\([\'\"]([^\'\"]+)', href)
        event_target = match[1]

        payload = {i['name']:i.get('value','') for i in soup.select('input[name]')}
        payload['__EVENTTARGET'] = event_target
        payload.pop('cmdSearchNew', None)

        print('-------------->',payload['__EVENTTARGET'])

    print('DONE')
```

Comment: It appears to be working in the right way @Dimitri. I'll let you know after I finish the test with a few different dates. Thanks.